# JSON schema help, array of objects

Tags: json

I am trying to write a JSON object where the key "pStock" is the total stock of an array of bike sizes 'size'. Each size has an inventory or 'count'. I have two versions of the same code. the first one returns an error message even though the syntax looks correct to my eye.

```
  "pStock": [
 {
    "size": {
           "type": "string",
           "count": {
                 "type": "number"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Here is the second version which returns no errors but I'm not quite sure it's saying what I want it to say.

```
     "pStock":  {
            "type": ["object"],
            "size": {
                "type": "string",
                "count": {
                    "type": "number"
                }
            }
        }
```

EDIT 1

I appreciate all of these responses. I made a silly error in posting. Below is the correct "wrong" code that isn't working. I get the error. 'Error, schema is invalid: data/properties/pStock should be object,boolean
    at Ajv.validateSchema' Rephrasing. the below code still does not work and received the error 'Error, schema is invalid: data/properties/pStock should be object,boolean
    at Ajv.validateSchema'

```
    "pStock": [
            {
               "size": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "count": {
                            "type": "number"
                           }
                       }
                    } 

           ]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Count the opening and closing curly braces on your first JSON. It has 3 opening and 4 closing.

```
"pStock": [
 { // Open 1
    "size": { // Open 2
           "type": "string",
           "count": { // Open 3
                 "type": "number"
                } // Close 3
            } // Close 2
        } // Close 1
    } // Close what?
]
```

Just remove the last one and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing square bracket `]` on the `pStock` array because you have an extra brace `}` i.e.

```
  "pStock": [
 {
    "size": {
           "type": "string",
           "count": {
                 "type": "number"
                }
            }
        }
    } <--- this is wrong
]
```

should be

```
{
   "pStock":[
      {
         "size":{
            "type":"string",
            "count":{
               "type":"number"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first version should look like that:

```
"pStock": [
 {
    "size": {
           "type": "string",
           "count": {
                 "type": "number"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

You had too many } (line 7)

The second version does not represent what you wanted, it does not contain the array of sizes.
But you can create this (pStock with multiple keys of different sizes. Then in each size write the inventory/count):

```
"pStock": {
  "size1": {
    inventory: "5",
    count: 4
  },
  "size2": {
    inventory: "5",
    count: 4
  }
}
```